# Django - Invalid literal for int() with base 10 python django

Tags: python, mysql, django, literals

I added new ForeignKey in models with `default = 't'` and Django said

```
Django - Invalid literal for int() with base 10 't'
```

when I made migrations. Than I deleted that row but I still can't migrate because of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the primary key of the related model is an int (`id`s are int by default), the ForeignKey column is also an int.

What you can do now is to edit the generated migration file (`yourapp/migrations/000x_auto_xyz.py`) and delete the part that tries to set the default value. For example, if your migration file looks like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Application',
            fields=[
                ...
                ('myforeignkey', models.ForeignKey(to='otherapp.OtherModel', default='t')),
            ],
            ...
    ]
```

then just remove the `, default='t'` part and re-run `manage.py migrate`.